# Packing tree columns on property sheet entry change

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-emf

We have an RCP app which uses a `Tree` and its corresponding `TreeViewer`. This tree uses an `ObservableMapLabelProvider` which provides the label text and an `ObservableListTreeContentProvider` for the content. We're using `org.eclipse.jface.databinding-1.5.0-SDK-3.7.2`.

We supply an array of `IObservableMap` using `EMFObservables.observeMaps(contentProvider.getKnownElements(), new EStructuralFeature[])` to construct the `ObservableMapLabelProvider`.

We have an implementation of `IPropertySourceProvider` which seems to be used for populating the property view by overriding `getPropertySource(Object)`.

Now I can see that when I modify the property sheet entry for a label, `IPropertySource#setPropertyValue(Object, Object)` is invoked. I want to add a change listener to  our `ObservableMapLabelProvider` or `IObservableMap` to ensure that the tree columns get packed once the label text is modified. I tried adding change map listener to each element of `IObservableMap` but it doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions/pointers on where should I be adding the change listener to pack tree columns once label text is changed on the property sheet?

Answer (score 1):

The *Properties* view part is implemented by the [PropertySheet](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.ui.views/src/org/eclipse/ui/views/properties/PropertySheet.java?h=master#n67) class, and it's worth reading its Javadoc.  `PropertySheet` is a type of `PageBookView`, a view that shows one of many managed pages.  The *Properties* view's current page shows the properties of the current selection.

So you could try obtaining the tree viewer from the *current page* from the *Properties* view part (based on its view ID, `org.eclipse.ui.views.PropertySheet`) via `getCurrentPage().getControl()`, and then perform whatever column voodoo is required.

Alternatively you could provide your own `IPropertySheetPage` that behaves how you want.